# AWS ElastiCache Redis - Why has SwapUsage slowly climbed just over 100MB dispite having FreeableMemory available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory-usage, redis, swap, amazon-elasticache

Starting around 7/28/2017 the SwapUsage started to climb for reasons I cannot figure out. I have spent many hours Googling and reading AWS documentation. At no point do we run out of FreeableMemory.

[CloudWatch Dashboard for the Redis server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzXsS.png)

Does anyone know what could cause this? There doesn't seem to be a performance hit as far as I can tell, but from what I've read there should be no swap usage at all, so I don't want to just ignore it.

[Redis Config Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNwiq.png)

I hope this is enough information, let me know if anything else would be helpful. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: did you learn anything that helped you resolve this or accept is as normal? I'm seeing similar behavior with a cluster we have.

Comment: @andrewmitchell Sorry to say I never figured it out, and now Redis isn't in our stack at the moment (for unrelated reasons). Let me know if you figure it out!